# How would I be able to include a parameter in this function?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, parameters

Below Is the code I created, its intended purpose is to traverse through a list and show up randomly on a label called "recs1", Including an IF statement saying that is "J15Watch" comes up, a different label would show "Out of stock". I was wondering if there would be any way to include a parameter in this code? I am currently in a computer science class, and my teacher wants me to include one.

```
function updateScreen() {
 var productRec = ["J15Watch", "COCO Parfum", "Chatutche brush", "New 2023 Collection",];
 var product;


if ("recs1" == "J15Watch") {
  setText("oosLabel", "Out Of stock");
 }


 for(var i = 0; i < productRec.length; i++){
 product = productRec[i];
  }
  var index = randomNumber(0, productRec.length-1);
  setText("recs1", productRec[index]);
}
onEvent("rec1", "click", function( ) {
updateScreen();


});
```

Initially I was able to complete a parameter for finding the tax of products on my app, however I haven't found a way to include it to this portion of my code, the recommendation portion.

Comment: `if ("recs1" == "J15Watch")` will never be true ... you are comparing a string against another string ... in no programming language or logic that would be true ... maybe you want `recs1` as function parameter and compare `if (recs1 == "J15Watch")` instead?

Comment: Yes thank you, I realized that last night and changed it. It still didn't work, basically recs1 is the label the product recommendations will be traversed in through a button. However I want it when J15Watch is in the recs1 label, to have "Out of Stock" Show on my Ooslabel, which is the label that will show the product is out of stock. Please help